# Is it possible to use RDMA Mellanox libraries from within a kernel module?

Tags: linux-kernel, infiniband, rdma, mellanox, ofed

I want to develop a kernel module that is able to send/receive RDMA messages. I am wondering if the Mellanox libraries can be called from kernel space.

**Can I call Mellanox RDMA functions from a kernel module?**

**Answer:** I have some working code here: https://github.com/jcarreira/disag-firebox

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the RDMA functionality provided by Mellanox devices and other HCAs can be accessed in the kernel through the API provided by the `ib_core` module, which is very similar to what `libibverbs` provides in user-space.

Comment: I saw in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38077746/46192) that there is the krping example code at https://www.openfabrics.org/downloads/krping/

Comment: krping has compatibility issues. It comes with few patches but the patches are failing.

(rdma_krping: disagrees about version of symbol rdma_disconnect) is one of the many similar errors that I get. I have also copied Modules.symver from ofa-kernel but it didnt solve the issue. Can you identify the problem/mistake I am making?

I have tried it on (kernel 4.4, ubuntu 14.04 and mlnx-ofed 3.3) and (kernel 3.5, ubuntu 12.04 and mlnx-ofed 3.3)