# RDMA API for Linux kernel

Tags: kernel, infiniband, rdma

Is there an API for **RDMA (Infiniband)** that can be used in kernel Space? Most of the API's that I have found are user Space. kDAPL and kAL can be used in the linux kernel; however, I have not yet found sample code to use these API's. Can somebody help me with sample code for RDMA in kernel space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the "krping" test - it is just what you need.
It uses RDMA-CM to establish connection and run some RDMA traffic.

Download it from [OpenFabrics website](https://www.openfabrics.org/downloads/krping/)

Comment: I am able to compile the module on (ubuntu 14.04, kernel 3.14 and mlnx-ofed-3.3). However, when I try to insert the module I get 
[  446.242522] rdma_krping: disagrees about version of symbol ib_create_cq
[  446.242525] rdma_krping: Unknown symbol ib_create_cq (err -22)
[  446.242533] rdma_krping: disagrees about version of symbol ib_alloc_fast_reg_page_list
[  446.242534] rdma_krping: Unknown symbol ib_alloc_fast_reg_page_list (err -22)......

I have also tried copying the Module.symvers to the directory but I get the same errors.